# Query about how to unpack a packed binary data

Tags: perl, pack, unpack

I have a packed binary data using below code:
my $binarydata .= pack ("H2" , $no);

This gives me some binary data which is not in readable format.

I need to take this binary data and convert back to ascii using unpack.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The inverse of

```
my $single_byte_str = pack("H2" , $two_hex_digits);
   or
my $single_byte_str = pack("C" , hex($two_hex_digits));
   or
my $single_byte_str = chr(hex($two_hex_digits));
```

is

```
my $two_hex_digits = unpack("H2" , $single_byte_str);
  or
my $two_hex_digits = sprintf("%02x", unpack("C" , $single_byte_str));
  or
my $two_hex_digits = sprintf("%02x", ord($single_byte_str));
```

Comment: Another issue which i am facing is when i pack value "a" using command pack("H2", "0a") i am getting value " " and a new line. so when i try to unpack this using command unpack ("H2" , "  ") i am getting value "20". Any idea why this is coming?